# Is there a way to prevent the configuration of tabbar items?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I constructed a tabbar with more than 5 tabs and the remainders were automatically added into the "More" view. That is fine, but along with that, the user is able to "Edit" the configuration of the app's tabs.

I do not want the user to be able to do that. Is there a way to prevent the user from doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [UITabBarController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Search for "customizableViewControllers"

> customizableViewControllers
>
> The subset of view controllers managed
>   by this tab bar controller that can be
>   customized.
>
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray
>   *customizableViewControllers
>
> Discussion
>
> This property controls which items in
>   the tab bar can be rearranged by the
>   user. When the user taps the More item
>   on the tab bar view, a custom
>   interface appears displaying any items
>   that did not fit on the main tab bar.
>   This interface also contains an Edit
>   button that allows the user to
>   rearrange the items. Only the items
>   whose associated view controllers are
>   in this array can be rearranged from
>   this interface. If the array is empty
>   or the value of this property is nil,
>   the tab bar does not allow any items
>   to be rearranged.
>
> Changing the value of the
>   viewControllers property (either
>   directly or using the
>   setViewControllers:animated: method)
>   also changes the value of this
>   property. When first assigned to the
>   tab bar controller, all view
>   controllers are customizable by
>   default.

Basically what you have to do is use the following code, to set the value to nil:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers=nil;
}
```

Cheers,
VFN

Comment: Note please that you must have tabBarController defined prior to this step or it will not work..

Answer (score 1):

```
// 'Move view' customization
// MORE tab bar items 'More view'
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
  self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers=nil;

  UIViewController  * moreController =
  [[self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] ;
  UITableView * moreTableView = ( UITableView *)  [moreController view];
  [moreTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  [moreTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
```